# can't find .csv file

Tags: java, file, csv, load

So my problem is that I need to load a `.csv` file from my program
this is my folder structure.

```
-IP1-Java ( workspace folder)
  -TP10 (program main folder)
      - Labyrinthe.java (main program)
      - Labyrinthe1.csv  (the file i have to "load")
```

But when I run Labyrinthe.java, I found this :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: labyrinthe1.csv (The specified file can not be found)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
    at Labyrinthe.chargeLabyrinthe(Labyrinthe.java:11)
    at Labyrinthe.main(Labyrinthe.java:143)
D:\Bureau\Cours\Licence_Informatique_Diderot\Semestre-1\IP1-Java\labyrinthe1.csv
```

I translated it a bit, because it was in french

When I put the labyrinthe1.csv file in the IP1-Java folder
it works fine,
but this will create a mess in my files
so i have to put everything related with this program in TP10 folder
I tried this :

```
-IP1-Java ( workspace folder)
  -TP10 (program main folder)
      - Labyrinthe1.csv  (the file i have to "load")
      -aaa 
          - Labyrinthe.java (main program)
```

I created a file named "aaa" in TP10, and placed here the Labyrinthe.java
file is but that also did not work.

I have to specify that there is no problem in my program, it was coded by my teacher, and everything worked when i tried it on school's computer.
i even removed all spaces from my folder's name in case if it was the problem

I placed the function who load the file
as i already said, it was coded by my teacher, and it worked

```
public static int[][]chargeLabyrinthe(final String nomFichier) {
    int[][] labyrinthe = {};
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(nomFichier)).useDelimiter("\n");
        int c = 0;
        // On compte le nombre de lignes
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            c = c + 1;
            final String tmp = sc.next();
        }
        labyrinthe = new int[c][];
        sc = new Scanner(new File(nomFichier)).useDelimiter("\n");
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            final String ligne = sc.next();
            final String[] splitLigne = ligne.split(",");
            labyrinthe[i] = new int[splitLigne.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < splitLigne.length; j = j + 1) {
                labyrinthe[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(splitLigne[j]);
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Probleme dans la lecture du fichier " + nomFichier);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return labyrinthe;
}
```

Comment: what string is contained in the "nomFichier" variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can use the standard *Maven* project structure (Maven is a project management tool):

> - src: root source folder
>
>   - main: main source folder
>
>     - java: java sources classified by package
>     - resources: resource files used in your different classes
>   - test: test source folder
>
>     - java: java sources used for testing *src/main/java* classes, using the same package classification
>     - resources: test resource files
> - target: java compiled classes

In your case, you would have something like that:

> - src
>
>   - main
>
>     - java
>
>       - *ip1.tp10.Labyrinthe*: java source containing your method *chargeLabyrinthe*
>   - test
>
>     - java
>
>       - *ip1.tp10.LabyrintheTest*: java source allowing to test your *Labyrinthe* object.
>     - resources
>
>       - *tp10/Labyrinthe1.csv*: the CSV file used for test scope.

And with that structure, you should be able to load the resource file *Labyrinthe1.csv* from the *LabyrintheTest* class using the argument "*tp10/Labyrinthe1.csv*".

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file you're looking for is written like `Labyrinthe1.csv`, but in your Exception the file that it is looking for is called `labyrinthe1.csv`.

Are you sure you're using the right file name?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, i even tried the "Labyrinthe1.csv" , but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I'd think if the file is in the same place as your main class (program main folder) and this was a java project structured as `src/main/java` then the variable `nomFichier` should be something like `src/main/java/Labyrinthe1.csv`

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand well what you call "structured project"
i just have a file in which one i have the .java and the .csv
i don't have any src files

Comment: Is this somewhere public where we can view the structure of the project?